# Как узнать директорию, в которой лежит исполняемый файл

Tags: php

Как при запуске скрипта с консоли вывести полный путь до исполняемого файла?
Нашёл функцию `pathinfo()`, но там нужен сам путь.

Comment: путь до какого файла ? может вы имеете ввиду текущий путь http://php.net/manual/ru/function.getcwd.php

Comment: @Mike `cwd` может вообще ничего общего не иметь с тем, где лежит исполняемый файл, пока пользователь туда руками через `cd` не перейдет, к примеру, и там не запустит скрипт

Comment: @teran А я не толковал вопрос как вопрос про путь до выполняемого скрипта

Comment: @Mike исправил. Да, путь нужен до выполняемого скрипта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примените функцию [realpath](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.realpath.php).

```
<?php echo realpath($argv[1]) . PHP_EOL;
```

---

Использование:

```
php ваш_сценарий.php интересующий_файл.txt
```

Вывод:

> /home/mymedia/интересующий_файл.txt

Comment: а что вы там в `argv[1]`  увидеть планируете, если имя выполняемого файла  в `argv[0]` содержится, во первых. А во вторых, `realpath` из имени файла, путь к нему вряд ли сотворит, или нет?

Comment: _> что вы там увидеть планируете_ - первый аргумент командной строки; _> realpath из имени файла, путь к нему вряд ли сотворит_ - вернёт, вернёт, только файл должен существовать

Comment: ага ага. вернет он вам `notice: undefined index 1`. а в `realpath` пустую строку для этого эффекта надо передать, а выведет он `cwd`. В справке по вашей ссылке так и написано.

Comment: скажите мне, как программист программисту, вы командной строкой пользоваться умеете?

Comment: Товарищи, тут вообще беда. На момент написания ответа - он был верным. Но потом условие задачи изменили - теперь требуется найти путь не до "файла", а до "исполняемого файла". Что в этом случае делать нужно? Исправить ответ? или вернуть назад вопрос? Или внести в ответ оба варианта? Как ни крути, а mymedia незаслуженно минус получил.

Answer (score 4):

Есть для этого переменная **DIR**

```
<?php
echo __DIR__;
?>
```

Comment: `__DIR__` это не переменная,а константа. а в случая заинклуженного файла, будет возвращена его директория, а не директория, к примеру, исполняемого (запущенного непосредственно консоли) файла